# Line of best fit

Tags: python

Can someone help me in this code, im having a problem in my input saying it could not convert
string to float.

```
import statistics 
import numpy as np

print("When entering some values it should be like this (1,2,3,4,5)")
xs=np.array(input("Enter some values of x coordinate: "), dtype=np.float64)
ys=np.array(input("Enter some values of y coordinate: "), dtype=np.float64)
  
    
def line_slope_intercept(xs,ys):
    
    m=(((statistics.mean(xs)*statistics.mean(ys))- statistics.mean(xs*ys))/
       ((statistics.mean(xs)*statistics.mean(xs))-statistics.mean(xs*xs)) )
    b=statistics.mean(ys)-m*statistics.mean(xs)
    return m, b
m,b=line_slope_intercept(xs,ys)

print(format(m,".2f"))
print(format(b,".2f"))

print("y=",format(m,".2f"),"x","+",format(b,".2f") )
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full traceback. [Ask], [mre], the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` cannot accept a list of values. By default, it is a string so you have to convert it to float. If you input `(1,2,3,4,5)` to it, surely it cannot convert that string into an array.

I propose another solution:

```py
print("When entering some values it should be like this (1,2,3,4,5)")
xs = input("Enter some values of x coordinate: ")
ys = input("Enter some values of y coordinate: ")
xs=np.array([float(x) for x in xs[1:-1].split(',')], dtype=np.float64)
ys=np.array([float(x) for x in ys[1:-1].split(',')], dtype=np.float64)
```

When you input `(1,2,3,4,5)` as a string, `[1:-1]` will take all characters from the first index to before the last index, so it will return the string `1,2,3,4,5`. Then we use `split(',')` to split the string into elements that are separated by `,` in the string, convert it to float and use it as usual.

Comment: owww thankss that solved my problem

Comment: Consider marking it as "answered" for others to see it too!